# undefined reference to boost library

Tags: c++, boost, static-linking

I am getting  `static` link errors to boost's non header only library. Let's solve it together:

The final binary is supposed to be built using libraries(`libbasemainif.a` for example) separately built as the higher layers. One of those layers, uses  `boost::filesystem`.

Have a look at the simplified vesrion of `g++` command:

```
g++  /mylis/1.a    /mylibs/2.a   
-L/myboost/Linux-x86_64/lib64 
-Wl,-rpath,/myboost/Linux-x86_64/lib64   -Wl,-Bstatic  
-lboost_thread-mt  -lboost_system-mt  -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_date_time-mt
-Wl,-Bdynamic 
-Wl,-rpath,/myinstall/usr/local/lib64 -L/myinstall/usr/local/lib64 -Wl,
-Bstatic -lmyblahblah-static -Wl,-Bdynamic **-lbasemainif** -lbaseif -ldl -rdynamic -lz -lrt 
-L/mypackage1/Linux-x86_64/debug/lib -L /mypackage2/18.1/Linux-x86_64/debug/lib -lpthread -Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/../lib64
```

and this is the error :

```
/blahblah/lib/libbasemainif.a(errorreportfile.o): 
In function `boost::filesystem3::remove(boost::filesystem3::path const&, boost::system::error_code&)':

/myboost/Linux-x86_64/include/boost/filesystem/v3/operations.hpp:411:
undefined reference to boost::filesystem3::detail::remove(boost::filesystem3::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

- If I remove `-Wl,-Bstatic` the g++ command executes successfully.But this is not an option in production.
- The `libboost_filesystem.a` is available. And all of the laibraries in every layer used boost from the same location.

Can you please tell me why I am getting this error? Thank you

Comment: seems like there is call to detail::remove with  last argument as boost::system::error_code*, but the definition is not provided for same causing undefined reference. boost::filesystem3::remove must be a overloaded function and there seems to be definition present for only one of them having boost::system::error_code& as last parameter. Try to provide second definition,.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass to gcc library that implements function *after* the piece which references it. Something like: `-lbasemainif -lboost_filesystem-mt`. This is how gcc linker resolves dependencies.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409470/4074081) is great detailed explanation.

Comment: I'll be back !(arnold schwarzenegger)